# Pipeline Analog to Digital Converter

Tags: adc, analog

I was studying for my Design of Analog Circuits course and I have two questions about this ADC. If someone can explain me why in the figure below in the Pipeline Analog to Digital Converter, why Vin is compared with Vref/2 instead of Vref and why after doing the summation, the result is multiplied by a gain of 2? What does that has to be with functionality of the ADC.

[image: Pipeline ADC]

Comment: If Vref is the full scale range, then above what voltage must the signal be for the MSB to be set?

Comment: If Vin > Vref/2, then MSB = 1. If Vin < Vref/2, then MSB = 0. Why is that? Why comparing with Vref/2?

Comment: If you have to ask that, you need to go back to the very beginning and understand what an in general ADC does, more specifically how voltages map to binary codes.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison with vref/2 is because that is the place-value of the MSB of the ADC output.

the next bit has a value of 1/4 vref, so the difference value is doubled before comparison with vref/2